# Rxjava onNext not firing via retrofit observable

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-android

I have this simple retrofit2 api interface which contains

```
interface Api {
    @GET(BuildConfig.END_POINT) Observable<Response> fetchData();
}
```

So everything is fine when I'm doing a fresh request 
but let say I fire a request and I un-subscribe immediately and then I try to fire new request it returns nothing.

So, in code it looks something like this:

in Activity::onPause I perform un-subscription and in Activity::onResume I fire the request again.

My request looks something like this::

```
api.fetchData()
    .timeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .doOnNext(new Action1<Response>() {
        @Override public void call(Response response) {
            list = response.getDataForList();
        }
    }).flatMap(new Func1<Response, Observable<List<Object>>>() {
        @Override public Observable<Object>> call(Response response) {
            return Observable.just(list);
        }
    });
```

When I tried debugging it, the call is made but doOnNext() is not called. None of the lifecycle methods are called.

And just for clarification from here I'm just returning the observable which I'm using it somewhere else where I'm observing on main thread and subscribing on IO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use doOnNext, just map. And try to get use to use lambdas, make your code much readable.

```
api.fetchData()
.timeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.map(response -> response.getDataForList())
.flatMap(list -> Observable.just(list));
```

Now as concept, every time that some observer subscribe to this observable consume the items, then observable automatically unsubscribe the observer. So you don't have to worry about unsubscribe anything.

You can see some practical examples here.  https://github.com/politrons/reactive

Comment: or just `.flatMap` with `.flatMap(response -> Observable.just(response.getDataForList())`

Comment: yep, that´s even better. But since the guy seems he is starting with RxJava baby steps XD

Comment: But what's wrong in my approach. What If I really want to control the un-subscription depending upon the activity/fragment lifecycle.

Comment: You can, but I just let you know that unsubscription is done automatically.

Comment: Ahhh I see. Thanks :)
Also why doOnNext is not a viable option here?

Comment: The problem still exists if I perform the un-subscription as soon as I make the request and then try to send the request again.

Comment: If you dont want to unsubscribe never the observer you can use relay. Take a look here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/relay/Relay.java

Comment: I still don't get what's wrong with doOnNext? Can you please clarify..? Thanks

Comment: So I resolved my problem and just to add the main issue was I was using composite subscription and I was calling unsubscribe which as per docs
Unsubscribes itself and all inner subscriptions.
After call of this method, new Subscriptions added to CompositeSubscription will be unsubscribed immediately.  [link](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subscriptions/CompositeSubscription.html#unsubscribe())